# Chats Google: Exibir total acima da coluna e grid mostrar 1 a 1

Tags: php, mysql, google-charts

Tenho o seguinte chart:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso exibir as linha de 1 a 1 e exibir o numero também do total no topo da coluna.

Sei que os dois darão o mesmo resultado, e que tenho 2 situações diferentes,pois em 1 caso terei que mostrar o total e no outro mudar a quantidade das linhas.

Estou usando o seguinte chart:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exibir os dados de um em um, você precisa personalizar o `vAxis`. Exemplo:

```
vAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
         min: 0,
         max: 10
     },
     ticks: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
},
```

E para exibir o número do total no topo da coluna, dentro das `options` coloque uma `annotations` com `alwaysOutside: true`:

```
annotations: {
    textStyle: {
         fontSize: 12,
    },
    alwaysOutside: true
}
```

Código exemplo completo:

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 5, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 7, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 9, "gold"],
        ["Blue", 3, "blue"],
        ["Red", 2, "red"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
           { calc: "stringify",
             sourceColumn: 1,
             type: "string",
             role: "annotation" },
            2]);

      var options = {
           title: "Teste Column Char",
           width: 600,
           height: 400,
           bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
           legend: { position: "none" },
           vAxis: {
                viewWindow: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 10
                },
                ticks: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
           },
           annotations: {
                textStyle: {
                   fontSize: 12,
                },
                alwaysOutside: true
           }
     };

     var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
     chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32cvvatv/).